# How to handle line-breaks in a table of contents with InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I'd like to build up a table of contents following this layout:

```
           Level 01     sub-level 1.1
                        sub-level 1.2
                        sub-level 1.3

           Level 02     sub-level 2.1
                        sub-level 2.2
```

Note that there is no line break after each Level 1.

How is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: Welcome Yako. Have you tried using tabs? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFx3WQh5HaA

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you saying you want visual space before Level 02 but not before sub-level 2.2? Put space-before into your paragraph style. Or are you saying you want all of Level 02 to stay together and not break over a column? Try "Keep Together" in Paragraph Options.

Comment: Tabulations are not really the problem as they can be handled through the paragraph styles. The question is to find how to put the parent item on the  same line than its first child. Best would have been to be able to remove the line break through the TOC styles, but it's not possible, at least in the 9.0 version.

Comment: Does anyone has an idea why this question was downgraded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for this InDesign TOC limitation.

The aim is to have a parent item on the same line than its first child. However, it seems that it's not possible to get rid of the line break using InDesign TOC styles.

So the workaround is to simulate a visal alignment by assigning a vertical offset in the parent's paragraph style. Then, left-indents or tabulations marks on the child's paragraph styles can be used to prevent any overlapping situations.

An other option would be to replace line-break by a tabulation after TOC generation, and to style the results. But the job will have to be made again after each TOC update, and for each TOC of your book if you have several.